# Problem with fraction $\frac{2+\frac{5}{a}-\frac{3}{a^2}} {2-\frac{5}{a}+\frac{2}{a^2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I worked on the fractions in the denominator and the numerator separately.Making sure they all had the same denominator in each individual side. However, my answer is incorrect. What have I done wrong. Please when giving me an answer, convince me. Thanks. [image]

Comment: Better to remove word complex from title since it makes confusion of complex numbers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number

Comment: Btw, your answer is correct.

Comment: What makes you think that you've done anything wrong? This answer seems just about right.

Comment: The book says the answer is (a+3)/(a-2)?

Comment: Maybe you could write $\frac{2a^2+5a-3}{2a^2-5a+2}=\frac{2a^2-5a+2+(10a-5)}{2a^2-5a+2}=1+\frac{10a-5}{2a^2-5a+2}$

Comment: Are you familiar with [quadratic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation)?If you are solving first and second will help you factorize both denominator and numerator so you can cancel the $(2a-1)$ term

Comment: Okay. So for this problem I would use x= -b +/- √b^2-4ac/2a? What should "tip me off" to utilize this equation?

Answer (score 2):

You could go one more step ahead:

\begin{align}
\frac{2a^2+5a-3}{2a^2-5a+2}&=\frac{(a+3)(2a-1)}{(a-2)(2a-1)}\\
&=\frac{a+3}{a-2}
\end{align}

Comment: That would "mask away" the problematic value of $a=\frac12$ (though I'm not sure whether or not it's an issue).

Comment: @barakmanos I think to have the original fraction well defined we need $a\neq0$ and $a\neq \frac12$, or what do you think? (These are removable singularities)

Answer (score 2):

Your start is fine.

Both numerator and denominator here  a common factor of $\dfrac 1{a^2}$, which can thus be canceled. $$\require{cancel} \dfrac{\dfrac{2a^2+5a-3}{{a^2}}}{\dfrac{2a^2 - 5a +2}{{a^2}}}= \frac{\frac{1}{a^2}\cdot (2a + 5a -3)}{\frac 1{a^2}\cdot (2a^2 - 5a+2)}= \frac{2a^2 + 5a -3}{2a^2 - 5a + 2} = \frac{(2a-1)(a+3)}{(2a-1)(a-2)}$$

Cancel the common factor $(2a-1)$, to get $\dfrac{a+3}{a-2}.$

Comment: How did you factor that?

Comment: I utilize the "criss cross factoring method". Can you show me by utilizing it? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nz058Hil6rA

Comment: Question: Is there no issue with $a=\frac12$ (which yields $0$ in both the numerator and the denominator of the original expression)?

Comment: The original equation would not be defined either at that value, as $1/2, 2, 0$ are not in the domain of the function.

Comment: I was referring to the original expression (not equation BTW). In your final answer, the expression seems to be well defined for $a=\frac12$, whereas in the original expression, it is not (you can only say that it has a well-defined limit at $a=\frac12$, but not an actual value at that point).

Comment: $1/2$ is not in the domain of the original function (I said function, BTW, which is not the same as equation), so yes, it has to be excluded from the domain of the final expression.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is right you could have got there as well by multiplying the numerator and the denominator of the main fraction with $a^2$. Precisely$$\begin{align}\frac{2+\frac{5}{a}-\frac{3}{a^2}}{2-\frac{5}{a}+\frac{2}{a^2}}&=\frac{a^2(2+\frac{5}{a}-\frac{3}{a^2})}{a^2(2-\frac{5}{a}+\frac{2}{a^2})}\\&=\frac{2a^2+5a-3}{2a^2-5a+2}\\&=\frac{(2a-1)(a+3)}{(2a-1)(a-2)}\\&=\frac{a+3}{a-2}\end{align}$$
*Edit* realising that $2a^2+5a-3=(2a-1)(a+3)$ and $2a^2-5a+2=(2a-1)(a-2)$

Comment: Thanks for showing me that. For some reason whenever I see a one in the denominator I believe I have to place the multiplier there. Nevertheless, can you factor your final answer utilizing the "criss cross method"?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nz058Hil6rA

Comment: Yes of course I will edit my answer

Comment: Can you utilize the "criss cross method"?

Comment: @Cetshwayo  You can factor $2a^2 + 5a - 3$ by splitting the linear term.  We must find two numbers with product $2 \cdot -3 = -6$ and sum $5$.  They are $6$ and $-1$.  Hence,\begin{align*} 2a^2 + 5a - 3 & = 2a^2 + 6a - a - 3\\ & = 2a(a + 3) - 1(a + 3)\\ & = (2a - 1)(a + 3)\end{align*}  For $2a^2 - 5a + 2$, we must find two numbers with product $2 \cdot 2 = 4$ and sum $-5$.  They are $-4$ and $-1$.  Hence, \begin{align*} 2a^2 - 5a + 2 & = 2a^2 - 4a - a + 2\\ & = 2a(a - 2) - 1(a - 2)\\ & = (2a - 1)(a - 2)\end{align*}

Comment: Can someone show me how to factor this by utilizing the criss cross method. If it is not possible to do so, which method is sure to help me factor questions like these.

Comment: N. F. Taussig, what is this method of factoring called?

Comment: @Cetshwayo I call it factoring by splitting and grouping.  Sometimes it is called factoring by splitting the middle term or factoring by grouping.  There is a Khan Academy video describing the method here: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/multiplying-factoring-expression/factoring-by-grouping/v/factor-by-grouping-and-factoring-completely